# Prove or disprove: $R$ has unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove or disprove: If $A$ is a non-zero ring with unity and $f : A → B$ an injective ring homomorphism then $B$ has unity.

**Rough Sketch:** Since $A$ is a non zero ring with unity, let $a = 1_A$, where $a \in A$. Then, since $f$ is $1-1$, $f(a) = f(b)$

Is this even close? I think I am missing something here but not sure what it is!

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, B here is the codomain of $f$ so you would probably want to show that $f$ takes the identity of A to the identity of B.

Comment: $f(b)$ doesn't make sense when $b \in B.$

Comment: Isn't that how you show something is $1-1$

Comment: In this case, since $f$ is injective, you know that ker$f$=1.

Comment: No! To show one-one, one need to show that if $a, a' \in A $ with $f(a)=f(a')$ then $a=a'.$ The function $f$ is from $A$ to $B.$ So what is the meaning of $f(b)$?

Comment: @A.Wong Do you mean $f(1_A) = f(1_B)$?

Comment: Look at Krish's comment above. I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of $f(b)$. In particular, if you have $f(b)$ then by the way $f$ is defined, $b\in A$ and $f(b)\in B$.

Comment: @Krish that makes sense.

Comment: To move you along a little, do you know what the kernel of a one to one function looks like? If you do, do you know what $f$ does with its kernel?

Comment: Yes, I know the relation between $ker(f)$ and $f$ being $1-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false.

Condider for a counterexample $A= \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$ (with operations defined by coordinate).
The map $z \mapsto (z,0)$ is an injective ringhomomrpism, yet $B$ has no unity while $A$ of course has.

Your idea is good, as I understand it; but the problem is you cannot say much about element outside the image of $f$. (In more detail, you can say that for all $a \in A$ you have $f(a)=f(a1_A)= f(a)f(1_A)$ so $f(1_A)b = b$ for all $b \in f(A)$.)

Comment: Don't be sad. It can take some time to get used to such reasoning.

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess I need much more practice.